# Bar Button Items Not Appearing When iOS Simulator Is Ran

Tags: xcode, swift, error-handling

I added 5 bar button items on my main view controller and linked them into code.  I also created show segues from the bar button items to other view controllers.  Although, when I run the iOS simulator none of my bar button items appear.  Can someone help me?

[image: Picture of problem]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need constraints on your bottom bar, it's probably just not in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look, tested some versions (you didn't make it easy) and found that if you add bar button items but don't add a toolbar there appears to be a toolbar in the storyboard but not when you run the app, nothing appears. [image: storyboard]
[image: screen]
Instead, remove the items, add a toolbar, constrain it, then add the bar button items within it. You should have no more problems from there.

Good luck on your app! If you have any more questions, just send me a message.